# Is it possible to return to Emerald Isle?

Tags: might-and-magic-7-blood-and-honor

Is it possible to return to Emeral Isle after leaving it? I already completed the tournament there.

Two of my party members don't know how to use bows so I wanted to teach it to them and it seems that you can only learn it on Emerald Isle...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there is only one (hard) way to come back to *Emerald Isle*:

1. Kill the dragon on *Emerald Isle*.
2. Hope to loot a *Lloyd’s Beacon* scroll.
   (I guess that this is the English name; it’s *Leuchtfeuer* in German)
3. Cast it somewhere on *Emerald Isle*.
4. Leave the island. Now you can cast *Lloyd’s Beacon* to get back to *Emerald Isle* (but note that it doesn’t last very long if unskilled).

However, you can learn *Bow* also in **Tularean Forest** and in **Avlee**.

Answer (score 4):

According to some threads ([this](http://telp.org/cgi-bin/anyboard.cgi/mm7/tavern/anyboard?cmd=iYz&aK=23184&iZz=23184&gV=0&kQz=&aO=1&iWz=0) and [this](https://www.celestialheavens.com/forum/10/7110#:%7E:text=The%20scroll%20is,level%206%20stuff.)), **it is impossible to return to the Emerald island**. The accepted [answer by unor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162425/is-it-possible-to-return-to-emerald-isle#162443) is theoretically correct, but practically, it has one caveat:

- The dragon which the party encounters in Emerald island's Dragon cave is [Morcarack](https://mightandmagic.fandom.com/wiki/Morcarack), a unique version of "common" Red Dragon, but without resistances.
- The [treasure Morcarack drops](https://www.angelfire.com/id/mmvii/monsters.html#:%7E:text=Red,L6%20item) is **400d10 gold + Level 6 item**.
- However, **Scroll of Lloyd’s Beacon can only appear as a Level 4 & 5 treasure**, according to [MM7 random item generation tables](https://sorcerers.net/Games2/DaveO/mm7/mm7risb.html#:%7E:text=Lloyd%E2%80%99s%20Beacon%20(scroll),0,-Stun).
- This means that **Scroll of Lloyd’s Beacon cannot be dropped by Morcarack**.
- And since there is no other monster powerful enough to drop Level 4 or 5 items, **Scroll of Lloyd’s Beacon cannot be obtained on Emerald isle**.

Thus practically, **returning to Emerald isle is impossible**.

The only possible way to get back to Emerald island seems to be by using the [Maestro MOD](http://mmgames.ru/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=110&Itemid=207&lang=en).